# Threading in Python takes longer time instead of making it faster?

Tags: python, multithreading, time, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I wrote 3 different codes to compare having threads vs. not having threads. Basically measuring how much time I save by using threading and the result didn't make any sense.

Here are my codes:

```
 import time



def Function():

    global x 
    x = 0

    while x < 300000000:
        x += 1
    print x

e1 = time.clock()
E1 = time.time()

Function() 

e2 = time.clock()
E2 = time.time()

print e2 - e1
print E2 - E1
```

When I ran this, I got this as output:

```
26.6358742929

26.6440000534
```

Then I wrote another function as shown below and split counting up to 300 million into counting 3, 100 millions:

```
 import time




def Function():

    global x 
    x = 0

    while x < 100000000:
        x += 1
    print x

def Function2():

    global x 
    x = 0

    while x < 100000000:
        x += 1
    print x       


def Function3():

    global x 
    x = 0

    while x < 100000000:
        x += 1
    print x 

e1 = time.clock()
E1 = time.time()

Function() 
Function2() 
Function3() 

e2 = time.clock()
E2 = time.time()

print e2 - e1
print E2 - E1
```

The output of the following function was:

```
26.0577638729

26.0629999638
```

and lastly I created 3 threads and ran each function on a single thread:

```
import time
import threading

e1 = time.clock()
E1 = time.time()

def Function1():

    global x 
    x = 0

    while  x < 100000000:
        x += 1
    print x


def Function2():

    global x 
    x = 0

    while x < 100000000:
        x += 1
    print x    


def Function3():

    global x 
    x = 0

    while x < 100000000:
        x += 1
    print x    



new_thread1  = threading.Thread(target = Function1() , args = ())

new_thread2  = threading.Thread(target = Function2(), args = ())

new_thread3  = threading.Thread(target = Function3(), args = ())


e1 = time.clock()
E1 = time.time()

new_thread1.start()
new_thread2.start()
new_thread3.start()

e2 = time.clock()
E2 = time.time()

print e2 - e1
print E2 - E1
```

The out put of this one was:

```
0.000601416222253

0.0
```

These numbers make no sense to me. I'm just trying to measure how much time does threading save me. I've looked up in the documentation and using  `time.time`
and `time.clock` made sense to me, but it doesn't make sense here. Also, the actual time for 1st and 2nd snippet were about 10 seconds and 3rd one about 5

Comment: or might be that he is calling the functions when he creates the threads ... those timings mean nothing at all

Comment: Threading lets you do other work while one thread is blocked on I/O. Your functions are all compute-bound; they are limited only by how much CPU time they can get, and with a single process, the time spent with thread management is just time taken away from actually computing.

Comment: @chepner how can I make it faster?

Comment: You need to use multiple processes, so that each function runs in a process on a separate CPU.

Comment: @chepner so I have to use multiprocessing instead of threading?! 
I assumed threading would work on this. If I have non-computational work, would threading speed up my code?
Sorry for multiple question. New to programming here.

Comment: You thought wrong :) An example of where threading is useful would be two threads that both access disk occasionally. While one thread is blocked waiting for a disk read (or write) to complete, you can switch to the other thread which may have non-I/O work to do.

Comment: @OpenCv In most programming languages, threads would do what you expect here. However, Python has a design limitation (look up the Global Interpreter Lock to learn more) that prevents more than one thread from executing CPU operations at a time, even if you have multiple CPU cores to work with. This means using multiple threads for CPU-bound work doesn't improve performance. In Python, threads can only improve performance in I/O bound work.

Comment: Threading can also help in situations where progress is more important than finishing. For example, for 10 users trying to load a webpage that could be transmitted in 10 seconds, it might be better if everyone received 10% of the file after 10 seconds than for one user to receive 100% of the file while the other 9 are still waiting for it to start. (Which is actually just a form of I/O bound work, if the user can't read the 10% on their screen before the server starts sending more data.)

Comment: @dano thank you for explaining. I'm just trying to really understand this. I'm ultimately trying to use threading for image processing and in the documentation it says image processing programs happen outside of GIL. here's what i read: "Note that potentially blocking or long-running operations, such as I/O, image processing, and NumPy number crunching, happen outside the GIL" I was just trying to test out time in the code above. So If I use the functions I have for image processing using threading, I wouldn't have an issue?

Comment: @OpenCv Anything that runs outside of the GIL should run in parallel across CPUs. And yes, it's true that there are certain libraries that use C-extensions that  can do CPU-bound processing outside the GIL. So if your image processing library releases the GIL to do its processing, then that can run in multiple threads in parallel across CPUs. Anything else that happens in the threads will need the GIL, and won't run in parallel. If the vast majority of the work the thread is doing releases the GIL, then you should see improved performance without needing to use `multiprocessing`.

Comment: @OpenCv edited my answer to more directly address your example code ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are calling it wrong ....

```
 new_thread1  = threading.Thread(target = Function1 , args = ())
```

note that you should not CALL the function when you create the thread

those timings really mean nothing they are both essentially zero because all you are timing is 3 instant return function calls to start

note to get the output you will need to wait for each thread to finish (since your current code does not do this )

## EDIT FOR MORE INFO

with threading you are locked by the gil to one python instruction at a time... typically this is not a problem since you are usually waiting on disk io... In your example code however it is 100% computation so threading really doesnt improve your time ... Multiprocessing may as demonstrated below

```
import time
import threading
import multiprocessing

def fn():
    '''since all 3 functions were identical you can just use one ...'''
    x = 0
    while  x < 100000000:
        x += 1
    



def TEST_THREADS():
    new_thread1  = threading.Thread(target = fn , args = ())
    new_thread2  = threading.Thread(target = fn, args = ())
    new_thread3  = threading.Thread(target = fn, args = ())
    new_thread1.start()
    new_thread2.start()
    new_thread3.start()
    new_thread1.join()
    new_thread2.join()
    new_thread3.join()

def TEST_NORMAL():
    fn()
    fn()
    fn()
    
def TEST_MULTIPROCESSING():
    new_thread1  = multiprocessing.Process(target = fn , args = ())
    new_thread2  = multiprocessing.Process(target = fn, args = ())
    new_thread3  = multiprocessing.Process(target = fn, args = ())
    new_thread1.start()
    new_thread2.start()
    new_thread3.start()
    new_thread1.join()
    new_thread2.join()
    new_thread3.join
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    '''It is very important to use name == __main__ guard code with threads and multiprocessing'''
    import timeit
    print "Time to Run 1x: %0.2fs"%(timeit.timeit(fn,number=1),)
    print "NORMAL:%0.2fs"%(timeit.timeit(TEST_NORMAL,number=1),)
    print "Threaded: %0.2fs"%(timeit.timeit(TEST_THREADS,number=1),)
    print "Multiprocessing: %0.2fs"%(timeit.timeit(TEST_MULTIPROCESSING,number=1),)
```

I get the following output

```
Time to Run 1x: 3.71181102665
NORMAL:11.0136830117
Threaded: 23.392143814
Multiprocessing: 3.80878260515
```

Comment: @joran_beasley does everything else seem right?! now I'm getting 0.0523433269691
0.0499999523163
and the code is significantly faster. but on the other hand the 1st and 2nd code didnt take 26 seconds

Comment: no you have a bunch of problems ...start your timer on the first line of your code ... and stop it after all your threads rejoin (using threadX.join() which will wait for the thread to finish)

Comment: @joran_beasley as in 
new_thread1.start()
new_thread1.join()
new_thread2.start()
new_thread2.join()
new_thread3.start()

Comment: no start all the threads ... and then join them all ... join will block the program until the thread returns

Comment: @joran_beasley thanks for helping out. would this do? http://pastebin.com/FW1Rqv05

Comment: @joran_beasley the times still don't make sense:
first code takes about 26 seconds, 2nd code takes 40  and 3rd one about 40 seconds. This is exact opposite of what i want threading to do.... isn't threading supposed to speed up the process?

Comment: In python3.10 I get different results since threading is three times faster than normal mode.