# Python - Threading takes too much CPU

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, cpu

So I have a Python 3.7 program that uses Threading library to multiprocess tasks

```
def myFunc(stName,ndName,ltName):
    ##logic here


names = open('names.txt').read().splitlines() ## more than 30k name
for i in names:

    processThread = threading.Thread(target=myFunc, args=(i,name2nd,lName,))
    processThread.start()

    time.sleep(0.4)
```

I have to open multiple windows to complete the tasks with different inputs, but eventually I ran into a very laggy situation where I cant even browse my **OSX** , I tried to use the **multiprocessing** library to solve the issue but unfortunately, multiprocessing seems not to be working correctly in OSX .

Anyone can advise ?

Comment: You may find this useful to your query - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29523404/7841468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is to be expected. If `myFunc` is a CPU intensive task that takes time, you are potentially starting up to 30k threads doing this task which will use all the machine resources.

Another potential issue with your code is that Threads are expensive in term of memory (each thread uses 8MB of memory). Creating 30k threads would use up to 240GB of memory which your machine probably doesn't have, and will lead to an OutOfMemoryError.

Finally, another issue with that code is that your main routine is starting up all those threads, but not waiting for any of them to finish executing. This means that the last started threads will most likely not run until the end.

I would recommend using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to solve all those issues:

```py
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
def myFunc(stName,ndName,ltName):
    ##logic here


names = open('names.txt').read().splitlines() ## more than 30k name
num_workers = 8
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
    for i in names:
        executor.map(myFunc, (i, name2nd, lName))
```

You can play with `num_workers` to find a balance between amount of resources being used by this program and speed of execution that fits you.